# IMPORTHTML / Table Pull Issues

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to import weather forecasts for multiple sales markets, but the site I was using blocked Bot Crawl, so my ImportHTML function can't fetch the URL.

I found another site, but the table is formatted in calendar view instead of the list view.
Can I still pull this information into Google Sheets (GS) somehow? I've gotten it to pull information, but it just comes up as [TABLE] in GS.

**This is the code I was using to pull changing dates:**

```
=CONCATENATE("https://www.wunderground.com/calendar/us/ca/eureka/KACV/date/",$B$3,"-",$C$3,"?cm_ven=localwx_calendar")
```

**And the code to pull the completed URL's table into GS:**

```
=IMPORTHTML(A2, "Table", 1)
```

I want the first string of code to pull today's year and month from B3 and C3, and Concatenate, and then the second string of code pulls all that together and then pulls the desired table from the website, but I get a bunch of cells with [TABLE].

Answer (score 0):

There is an API that returns json. Look into documentation to see if there is an endpoint that meets your needs. For example, network tab shows the following for 15 day forecast

```
https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/15day?language=en-US&apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&geocode=40.95%2C-124.11&units=e&format=json
```

You would probably need to write your own script to handle this response though or use a tool like [ImportJSON](https://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json). With a little research it is highly likely you will find something suitable.

Explore 15 day forecast JSON [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d4ff43908bb1418aa6b53fc936c7b32c)